# how to Map Dropdown and dynamic checkbox values in array on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to fetch value of dropdown and checkbox in an array and pass to controller

Functionality:
When the checkbox is checked. get value of selected dropdown value and checkbox value in array

```js
function getData() {
  if ($("#Cohort_ID").val() == "" || $("#Cohort_ID").val() == "Select") {
    alert("Please Select Cohort");
  } else {
    var checkedCheckBoxesValueArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return {
        cohortid: $("#Cohort_ID").val(),
        studentid: this.value
      };
    }).get();
    alert(checkedCheckBoxesValueArray);
  }
}
```

This works fine only to get checkboxes value, when the dropdown changes the cohort id (dropdown) of previously selected item also change.

Html code

1. For Dropdown

   ```
                       @Html.DropDownList("Cohort_ID", null, "Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Program_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   </div>
               </div>
   ```
2. Checkbox

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#Program_ID").change(function () {

   ```
       $.ajax({
           async: true,
           cache: false,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf=8",
           type: 'GET',
           url: '/Students/getStudentsByFellowship',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: { programid: $("#Program_ID").val() },
           success: function (students) {
               var table = '<table id="tblStudents" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped"><thead><tr>';
               table += '<th>Sr. No</th><th>Appliaction No</th><th>Student Name</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Select</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
               $.each(students, function (i, stud) {
                   var checkbox;
                   checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="stdentcheckbox" value=' + stud.Student_ID + ' onclick="getData()">';
                       table += '<tr><td>' + parseInt(i + 1) + '</td><td>' + stud.ApplicationNo + '</td><td>' + stud.Name + '</td><td>' + stud.Mobile + '</td>';
                       table += '<td>' + checkbox + '</td></tr>';
               });
               table += '</tbody></table>';
               $("#studenttable").html(table);
               $("#studentdata").css("display", "block");
           },
           error: function (ex) {
               alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
           },
           failure: function (response) {
               alert('Error while fetching streams');
           }
       });
       return false;
   })
   ```

As the checkbox is checked dropdown value as cohortid and checkbox checked value as student id and to be passed to array. Removed when checkbox is deselcted.

Comment: It would help to see the HTML associated with this code too.

Comment: Also, please specify in each case what is the expected result. It's will help us to understand the logic.

Comment: The checkbox is dynamicaaly generated in each column of table and dropdown is seperate division.

Comment: @PoojaDhoot the html will explain to us better :)

Comment: Expected result is array of(Cohortid:Dropdown value,studentid: Checkbox value). I am fetching both the values but if i change selection of dropdown all other values of cohortid saved in that array changes, but the studentid(ie checkbox value) remains different

Comment: I have added html code

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand and I think I haven't the full picture.. How the `#Cohort_ID` dropdown connected to the `input`s? The dropdown is part of a Razor view but the `input`s are part of a javascript code, so, what is the relation between them?

Answer (score -2):

*Serialize form data it will gives you all the values*

Comment: Please read the guidelines on how to provide an effective answer. This is the third unhelpful answer of yours I've seen in the last 15 minutes now.